# nvcc generating invalid error compiling JNI code

Tags: java-native-interface, nvcc

```
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Sep__1_21:08:03_CDT_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.0, V9.0.176
```

The error is:

```
MyFile.cu(231): error: expression must have pointer type
```

The relevant code:

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_MyFile_convergeMatrixCuda (
    JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jfloatArray fxnMatrixJ, jfloatArray mulMatrixJ, jfloatArray addMatrixJ, 
    jfloatArray resultsJ, jint numRowsJ, jint numColsJ, jint maxIterations, jfloat epsilonJ)
{
    int     numRows = (int) numRowsJ;
    int     numCols = (int) numColsJ;
    int     maxIter = (int) maxIterations;
    float   epsilon = (float) epsilonJ;
    float   *fxnMatrixH = (*env)->GetFloatArrayElements (env, fxnMatrixJ, NULL);
```

GetFloatArrayElements returns a float*.  Replacing "(*env)->GetFloatArrayElements" with "env->GetFloatArrayElements" gets these errors:

```
float   *fxnMatrixH = env->GetFloatArrayElements (env, fxnMatrixJ, NULL);

MyFile.cu(231): error: argument of type "JNIEnv *" is incompatible with parameter of type "jfloatArray"

MyFile.cu(231): error: argument of type "jfloatArray" is incompatible with parameter of type "jboolean *"

MyFile.cu(231): error: too many arguments in function call
```

nvcc does work correctly when compiling non-JNI code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NVidia's documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html) states that

> Source files for CUDA applications consist of a mixture of conventional **C++** host code, plus GPU device functions.

`(*env)->GetFloatArrayElements (env, fxnMatrixJ, NULL);` is the way you'd invoke a JNI function in C. But in C++ it would be `env->GetFloatArrayElements(fxnMatrixJ, NULL);`

Comment: I tried that.  I get the "error: argument of type "JNIEnv *" is incompatible with parameter" error

Comment: According to what you wrote in your question, you tried `env->GetFloatArrayElements(env, fxnMatrixJ, NULL);`. Note that that is different from what I said you should write.